# Partytown implementation with React.js

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, partytown

I was trying to implement partytown in a React application but the partytown documentation is not clear and I am unable to find a good resource for partytown implementation. Please guide on how to implement partytown in React with a good example. Also, is there any way to check if partytown is implemented or not

Comment: were you able to find anything on this?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. However, if you switch to next.js, it handles it internally using partytown only when "worker" strategy is used in the Script tag that "next/script" exports. But there is also a trade-off that it's still experimental currently.

Comment: Yeah, thanks man! The docs gives an example of nextjs component integration for React. The creator should not hype it for react if he himself doesn't know how to integrate with it.

Answer (score -1):

In React application the party-town library can be used in the script tag to run 3rd party scripts.

Example:

```
<script
  type="text/partytown"
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
    __html: '/* Write your Script here*/',
  }}
/>
```

Or you can use this method to run an external Script.

```
 <script src="https://example.com/analytics.js" type="text/partytown" />
```

But for your code to be executed you need to import the Partytown component and set some configurations.

```
import { Partytown } from '@builder.io/partytown/react';

export function Head() {
  return (
    <>
      <Partytown debug={true} forward={['dataLayer.push']} />
    </>
  );
}
```

You can go through the documentation [here](https://partytown.builder.io/react) to see the list of configuration options available to you.

Comment: Yeah that much part I understood from the documentation but how and where do I use this 'Head' component?

Comment: @SahilAggarwal you could use something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet